# Exclude file types in CI triggers on Azure Devops Pipelines Builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm having trouble with setting up a build where commits with only changes to markdown files do not trigger the build.

On the build, I have continuous integration enabled with "include" branch filters.

To exclude changes to markdown files I setup a single ["exclude" path filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer#example) to `**/*.md`, which from my understanding of [file matching patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops) should recursively match all files that end in `.md`. However, when I push just a change to a markdown file, the build is still triggered.

I considered adding an "include" path filter with `/`, but the builds are still being triggered without it.

How do I specify specify to not build when only a certain file type was changed?

Comment: i think they work slightly differently in triggers, can you try `*.md` as an exclude pattern? another alternative is to use `[skip ci]` anywhere in the commit message.

Comment: Just tried changing it to `*.md` and pushed a change to a markdown and it triggered a build.

I don't suppose that there is any way to see why the build was triggered?

Comment: it says build reason on the build page, for example a PR validation build would say this: `Validation of branch 262 triggered today at 7:21 pm for XXX targeting %reponame% %branchname%`

Comment: Yes, but when a rolling build is triggered it doesn't say what rule triggered it. Here it would say `Rolling build triggered today at HH:mm pm for XXX %reponame% %branchname%`, but which rule triggered the rolling build?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of now, wild cards are not supported for these file path filters.

You're going to be forced into a different convention to bypass the trigger for these files.

Putting `.md` files in an explicit structure (ex: /docs) that you can exclude with the "pattern" given in the examples you linked `exclude: docs/`.

### Illustration:

Given the following director structure:

```
(repo)
\src
   |\d1
   |   \md
   |
    \d2
       \md
```

#### Try `**` as recursive inclusion prefix

With the following trigger specification to attempt an include on a directory using double wildcard syntax:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - /src/**/md/
```

When a change is made inside the `/md` directory, then the trigger **is not invoked**.

#### Try `**` as recursive exclusion prefix

With the following trigger specification to attempt to exclude a directory using double wildcard syntax:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/
    exclude:
      - src/**/md/
```

When a change is made to files in either `.../md` directory, the trigger **is invoked**.

#### Explicit path exclusion is successful

With the following trigger specification to attempt an exclude on a fully specified directory path (no wildcard syntax)

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/
    exclude:
      - src/d1/md/
```

When changes are made to a file inside `src/d1/md`, then the trigger **is not invoked**. When changes are made to files inside `src/d1` or any other part of the structure, then the trigger is invoked.

---

### Illustration with file names

This same behavior holds true for your specific desire to try and call out a group of files using `*.md`.

Given each directory has a `[variant]_README.md` file in it, the following is true:

#### Try `*` wildcard as file name

With the following trigger specification to attempt exclusion of any `.md` file under `src/d1/md/` from causing invocation, when changes are made to `src/d1/md/f1_README.md`, then the trigger **is invoked**.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/
    exclude:
      - src/d1/md/*.md
```

#### Try `*` as file name prefix wildcard

With the following trigger specification to attempt to exclude any file ending in `README.md` under `src/d1/md` from causing invocation, when changes are made to `src/d1/md/f1_README.md`, then the trigger **is invoked**.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/
    exclude:
      - src/d1/md/*README.md
```

#### Try `**` and `*` as recursive any file extension exclusion

With the following trigger specification to attempt exclusion of any `.md` file anywhere in the repository from causing invocation, when changes are made to `src/d1/md/f1_README.md` or any other `.md` file, then the trigger **is invoked**.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/
    exclude:
      - /**/*.md
```

With the following trigger specification to attempt to exclude any `.md` file in the repository from causing an invocation, when changes are made to `src/d1/md/f1_README.md` or any other `.md` file, the trigger **is invoked**.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/
    exclude:
      - /*.md
```

#### Full file path is successful

**CI is *NOT* triggered**
when changes are made to `src/d1/md/f1_README.md`

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/
    exclude:
      - src/d1/md/f1_README.md
```

Comment: Is it just me or does this explanation imply that include means do not trigger and exclude means do trigger?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: The reason it sounds this way is to highlight that the **`**`** does not represent a recursive wildcard.

Answer (score 11):

The newest update from 08/09/2021 made possible to use wild cards in [path filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#support-for-wild-cards-in-path-filters).

> Wild cards can be used when specifying inclusion and exclusion branches for CI or PR triggers in a pipeline YAML file. However, they cannot be used when specifying path filters. For instance, you cannot include all paths that match src/app/**/myapp*. This has been pointed out as an inconvenience by several customers. This update fills this gap. Now, you can use wild card characters (**, *, or ?) when specifying path filters.

So now it should be possible to ave triggers as follows:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - src/
    exclude:
      - '/**/*.md'
```